# Measuring a string with a different font AccessViolationException was Unhandled

Tags: c#, string, fonts, measure

In the following property of my custom label class, when the Font is set, it finds the new length of the displayed text, and changes the size of the label accordingly.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Font of Text Displayed
    /// </summary>
    public Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return _font;
        }
        set
        {
            _font = value;
            using (Graphics g = _parent.CreateGraphics())
            {
                SizeF soize = g.MeasureString(_text, _font);
                _size = new Size((int)soize.Width, (int)soize.Height);
                _width = _size.Width;
                _height = _size.Height;
            }
```

However on the line

```
SizeF soize = g.MeasureString(_text, _font);
```

I get this error: System.AccessViolationException {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

This only occurs when I change the font to a custom one that is embedded. Usually with most instances of my custom label this does not throw an error, even when the same font is used in the same way. It also sometimes seems to work without throwing the error but I do not know why it sometimes decides to work, and other times, not.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Random GDI+ related AccessViolationExceptions seem to most often be caused by the video driver. I would try two things:

1. Update your driver
2. Try this on a machine with a different manufacturer's video card (i.e. try an ATI if you have an Nvidia or vice versa).

Comment: I fixed the error, I had to call the Font change last for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I have the same problem. How did you fixed it? @ ρσݥzση